# Альтернатива функции map (Arduino) на python

Tags: python, map, arduino

Нужно перевести один диапазон значений в другой. Пишу на python. В скриптах arduino есть такая функция как map, интересно есть ли что-то подобное на python. Ниже описание функции map из arduino

```
map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)
```

Функция пропорционально переносит значение (`value`) из текущего диапазона значений (`fromLow .. fromHigh`) в новый диапазон (`toLow .. toHigh`), заданный параметрами.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это исходный код этой функции из [документации](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/)

```
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

На питоне, видимо, будет как-то так (код не проверял)

```
def arduino_map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
    return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
```

Comment: self первым входным элементом забыли указать. А так работает. Спасибо

Comment: @ЛАНТАН если в классе, то да. А я писал как отдельную функцию, не за что)

Comment: Не стоит использовать переопределение имен встроенных функций.

Comment: @mkkik я написал так только для ясности, но, возможно, и вправду было бы лучше поменять, спасибо